# Is it possible to remotely clone a running/live OS?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, ubuntu, deb

I have an active OpenVPN/OpenSSH connection to a remote server. Is it possible to clone the remote OS, save it to a local file (e.g., with `dd`) and run it locally in VirtualBox or something similar?

Comment: What filesystems are you using on the source machine? Is it physical or virtual? Are you using LVM or some other snapshottable device? Is there a database running on the source? What about other applications that have a high write rate to the filesystem? How accurate must the copy be - can some files be out of date with respect to others, or maybe corrupted by a write as it's copied? Please [edit] your question to provide the necessary context

Comment: Interesting question, but without the information requested by roaima, it simply cannot be answered.  Please don't hesitate to fill us in with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Granted you've stopped all the services/daemons like MySQL which continuously update its files, you could do the following:

- Install the same OS using a minimal configuration into a VM
- On a source OS: `sudo tar -cf /image.tar /bin /boot /etc /lib /lib64 /root /usr /var`
- Copy this tar to your VM
- Unpack the tar file e.g. into `/new`
- Now this part is a little tricky. Install mc (midnight  commander), run it under root/sudo, create `/old`, move all the above directories to it (*except* `/boot`), then move all the directories (again *except* `/new/boot`) from `/new` to `/`.

As for `/boot`. That depends on your UEFI/MBR configuration. In case of UEFI, replace all the files in `/boot/efi/EFI/yourdistro` and then move `/new/boot/{initrd*|vmlinuz*}` to `/boot`.

This all requires that you totally understand what you're doing and you know how EUFI/grub2 works. In case you don't consider yourself a powerful Linux user/IT pro, forget this answer.

Comment: I have done this for cloning raspberry pi's used in an embedded product.

Comment: Someone here apparently hates me. I keep getting downvotes for offering working tested solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using Raspberry Pi's used in an embedded product.
I remounted the main filesystem read-only and copied the SD-card block device over the network.
I doubt that you'd get good results using a system that is actively writing to disk as you clone it - either read-only mounts or filesystem snapshots are probably essential.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this, but i would attack this by setting up the filesystem so i can take snapshots of it while it is active (using btrfs or by setting up an lvm), then using the live system to package that snapshot how you would like, and sending it over the network to your computer.

I hope this helps!